# Trouble With Post Request to Slack Endpoint Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, slack-api

I'm having trouble posting to the slack endpoint through a ruby script I'm writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Notification Script Test

def send_slack_message
    slack_rooms = [ '#test_channel_notify' ]
    slack_token_file = (File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.slack_api_token'))
    slack_api_token = (File.open(slack_token_file).readlines)[0].chomp
    msg = 'This is a test message send'
    slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    %x{curl -X POST -d 'token=#{slack_api_token}\&channel=#{slack_rooms}\&text=#{msg}' '#{slack_url}'} 
end

send_slack_message
```

The curl command with all the parameters hardcoded in the command line works properly and my message gets posted:

```
curl -X POST -d 'token=xxxxx-11111111111&channel=#test_channel_notify&text=This is a test' 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
```

However from the script, I just get the following returned:

```
 Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   154  100    40  100   114    289    825 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   832
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated! Also I do not want to have to require any modules in order to do this, nor should I have to.

Comment: What are you expecting back? How do you know it didn't work? Why are you using curl instead of using any of several HTTP methods available to Ruby?

Comment: I don't want to download any modules including http, and I am expecting to see a message in my channel in slack. I am getting that from the command line, but not from my script.

Comment: There's a simple one in the standard Ruby lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was specifying an array for my channel, but only passing in a single channel into my command. When I removed the array and tested as:

```
slack_rooms = '#test-notification-channel'
```

It worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying your channel as an array, so if you don't specify which value, or index it'll be added as an array in your request. If you have more than one try iterating over every value within your `slack_rooms` array or just specifying the first element "`slack_rooms.first`".

```
%x{curl -X POST -d 'token=#{slack_api_token}&channel=#{slack_rooms.first}&text=#{msg}' #{slack_url}}
```

Note the `slack_url` is also a variable but in a curl request it doesn't need to be specified with quotes.

And you don't need the backslash-es to join the parameters, just the `&`.

Comment: Thanks for responding I found out the array was an issue as well. As far as using double vs single quotes in the data of the json request it makes no difference, tested both ways. Also, I updated the slack_url previously in the question, it just got copied in wrong.

Comment: You're welcome, funny enough, and yo'ure right it takes the values even if you use single quotes, I've edited, and the bad thing is through curl it doesn't give any output to see what went wrong.